# Depmod freezing up after bcwml-kernel-source install failure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers, freeze

I recently installed an a new piece of networking hardware into my Ubuntu/Windows dual boot PC. Windows worked as expected with the new hardware, but when I installed the necessary drivers for Ubuntu, the post-install script of `bcmwl-kernel-source` freezes up at `depmod`. The entire machine freezes up as well.

This failure seems to also messed with the other wireless drivers, since even the old hardware won't work anymore. The graphics will also not fill up the screen any more.

My new hardware is an Asus PCE-AC66 Wireless card, which I read in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315950/drivers-for-wireless-card-asus-pce-ac66) that `bcwml-kernel-source` should solve my driver needs.

The output from the crash:

```
Loading new bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom DKMS files...
First installation checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.8.0-26-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.8.0-26-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
  - Original module
    - No original module exists within this kernel
  - Installation
    - Installing to /lib/modules/3.8.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod
```

The computer then proceeds to freeze.

I have tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as suggested; it freezes just as fast in `depmod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to install with the newest version bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb download file, have a new problem with it under my new question [Linux Driver: Missing required config variable](https://superuser.com/questions/676515/linux-driver-missing-required-config-variable).  Installs great though!

Answer (score 0):

After screwing up my test laptop (10 years old) a few times for the same reason I decided to go through the DPKG manual for good.
The kernel downloaded is not functioning as it is supposed to for various possible reasons, lets say hardware is just too old....

just remove it from your system cause no matter how many times you try to configure it its going to be depmod error...

```
sudo dpkg --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

lets just do without THAT driver until someone finds a solution...cause even i'll be waiting for that.